# How can I set properties on an EventHub message in a Java Function?

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-eventhub

When using C# to write an Azure Function publishing an EventHub message as the output binding one can use the `Azure.Messaging.EventHubs.EventData` class as the output binding and set properties on the object before handing it over to the output binding:

```
var eventData = new EventData(serializedTelemetryData);
eventData.Properties["eventType"] = "com.microsoft.azure.monitoring.EtlEvent";
```

But the Java output binding seems to only allow `OutputBinding<T>`, where "T is a POJO or any native Java type". Is there an equivalent of the EventData class in Java that could be used for the binding and allow to set properties?

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation you can using `getProperties`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/api/com.azure.messaging.eventhubs.eventdata.getproperties?view=azure-java-stable#com-azure-messaging-eventhubs-eventdata-getproperties()

Example of Usage:

```
EventData eventData = new EventData(message);
eventData.getProperties().put("constant1", yourEntityHere);
eventData.getProperties().put("constant2", "ADD");
```

Comment: Which is great if you are sending an EventHub message from plain Java code, but I can't see how I have access to that when using a Java output binding for EventHub in an Azure Function?